# Jquery radio button Triggering On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im new to jQuery but have to get a solution together to add an alert to a generated form (so I cant change the divs, only tack JS and jQuery at the end).

I've been trying to create an alert when a certain radio button is clicked but I cant seem to get it to trigger, had a look through some other threads but no joy! (cant seem to get the code to format properly here!)

```
<div class="inputWrapper">
    <span id="tfa_3575" class="choices horizontal ">
        <span class="oneChoice">
            <input type="radio" value="tfa_3576" class="" id="tfa_3576" name="tfa_3575">
            <label class="label postField" id="tfa_3576-L" for="tfa_3576">Confirmed Submission</label>
        </span>
        <span class="oneChoice">
            <input type="radio" value="tfa_3577" class="" checked="" id="tfa_3577" name="tfa_3575">
            <label class="label postField" id="tfa_3577-L" for="tfa_3577">Keep as Draft</label>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have used the below but I cant get it work! Any Ideas what im doing wrong!
 The goal is to check which one is ticked and if one is ticked send an alert and edit button text (though I can manage that last bit!!)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:radio[name="tfa_3576"]').change(function(){
           alert("test");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a radio button, you change the "checked" state, not the value, therefore the 'change' event doesn't fire. Observe the 'click' event instead.

*And make sure the jQuery selector is correct.*

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working with a checkbox before, which then got changed to a radio button! Changed it .click and am completely comfortable messing with it now! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have a radio button with a name attribute of `tfa_3576`

```js
$('input:radio').change(function(){
       alert("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputWrapper">
  <span id="tfa_3575" class="choices horizontal ">
    <span class="oneChoice">
      <input type="radio" value="tfa_3576" class="" id="tfa_3576" name="tfa_3575">
      <label class="label postField" id="tfa_3576-L" for="tfa_3576">Confirmed Submission</label>
     </span>
    <span class="oneChoice">
      <input type="radio" value="tfa_3577" class="" checked="" id="tfa_3577" name="tfa_3575">
      <label class="label postField" id="tfa_3577-L" for="tfa_3577">Keep as Draft</label>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the name attribute set to the wrong value `tfa_3575`. Just change the name attribute from `tfa_3575` to `tfa_3576`

```
<input type="radio" value="tfa_3576" class="" id="tfa_3576" name="tfa_3576">
```

Comment: I couldnt change any of the <input> areas as they were generated, tried using the .click rather than the checked listener and it worked like a charm!